# How to detect intersection with SVG shape in Fabric.js?

Tags: svg, path, intersection, fabricjs

First of all see this example.

http://radykal.de/fabric/

I would like detect when the text is moving over the blue outline of the svg shape. The black shape is a SVG, which I am loading with `loadSVGFromURL()`.

Currently I am using the isContainedWithinObject() method to detect if the text is contained within the svg shape, but its using the rectangular bounding box of the svg shape for detection.

Is it possible to detect it with the actual path of the svg image?

Thank you.